# PHP unable to play .m3u8 live stream

Tags: php, video-streaming

I'm trying to play a live stream `.m3u8` video through the default web browser player using PHP's `readfile()`. However the player only seems to load the video but fails to play. Furthermore, I'm not getting any errors. Using the same code, I'm able to play prerecorded videos (for instance `.mp4`, prerecorded `.m3u8`) without any issues. Any ideas?

```
<?php

//Live video URL: https://abclive1-lh.akamaihd.net/i/abc_live01@423395/master.m3u8

//Pre recorded video URL: http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8

$url = $_GET['url'];

if (!$url) {
print "no URL";
} 


else {


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

header('Content-Type: application/x-mpegurl'); 

readfile($lastUrl); 

curl_close($ch);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For playing *.m3u8 files client needs to have a specific player that supports [HLS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming).

For playing in browser you could try [videojs](https://videojs.com/) + [videojs-contrib-hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) plugin.

For playing on desktop you could try using [VLC media player](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.ru.html). Just install it and open your `*.m3u8`.

To implement hls streaming you could use [nginx-vod](https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module) web server (modified nginx version). Here's a working [dockerized example](https://github.com/NYTimes/nginx-vod-module-docker) provided by NY Times.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, the m3u8 file plays flawlessly when input directly to the web browser, in my case chrome. For instance, this URL plays in the default web browser without any issues:  https://abclive1-lh.akamaihd.net/i/abc_live01@423395/master.m3u8, however when I try to execute it using my code, it loads the player but fails to start the video. Are there any headers that might be missing in the code?

Comment: Could you tell more about how are you playing m3u8 files? What web-server do you use? What video player?

Comment: I'm attempting to play the video through the default browser using the server as a proxy.  Prerecorded video files play flawlessly, even in external players such as vlc. I execute the code in this manner: http://myserver.com/code.php?url=http://linktolivestream.m3u8. The only issue I'm facing is playing live video.